# Как реализовать воспроизведение 2-х, 3-х, HTML5-аудио-плееров поочерёдным?

Tags: html5, web-audio

Как реализовать воспроизведение HTML5-аудио-плееров поочерёдным?
Первый проиграл, включился второй. Это необходимо для чтения через Yandex-Speach, он лимитирован на POST запрос. Я переменную делю на определённые части и тогда переменная проходит на синтез речи.
Но вручную включать второй плеер, после проигрыша первого, как-то не с руки. 
Возможно может быть заскриптовать это каким-то методом можно?
Собственно пример:

```html
плеер №1
<audio controls="controls" autoplay>
  <source src="https://namobilu.com/u/ring/f/689/083/nu_pogodi_o_sole_mio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<br><br>
плеер №2
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="https://namobilu.com/u/ring/f/048/033/magyar_radio_tanczenekara_vizisi_nu_pogodi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвойте второму плееру ID, скажем, **player2**. А в первый допишите

```html
<audio controls="controls" autoplay onended="document.getElementById('player2').play()">
```

Можно вместо двух плеееров обойтись одним:

```html
<audio controls="controls" autoplay onended="this.src='https://namobilu.com/u/ring/f/048/033/magyar_radio_tanczenekara_vizisi_nu_pogodi.mp3'; this.play()">
  <source src="https://namobilu.com/u/ring/f/689/083/nu_pogodi_o_sole_mio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!